# jQueryMobile Submit Button won't click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button, click

I've added a submit button to a form in my jQuery Mobile application using the following code:

```
$('<input data-theme=\"b\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">').click(self._performQuery);
```

This successfully adds the button to the form with additional parent elements for styling.  The overall markup created by this code looks like:

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" data-disabled="false"
class="ui-submit ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-b" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">Submit</span>
  </span>
  <input data-theme="b" type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false" />
</div>
```

Notice the button is wrapped inside other elements created by jQuery Mobile for styling purposes and has `class="ui-btn-hidden"`, results in the style `display: none`.

Since the button is hidden, it does not recognize the click event.  Is this a bug?  I haven't seen anything in the docs suggesting this behavior.  Can anyone offer a workaround?

---

**Edit**:
The form and page are both dynamically created using Javascript as well.

I've tried adding `.button()` before the `.click` in the code sample above and then the button didn't even render.

I've tried selecting the button after it has been added to the form and adding the `click` event with no luck.

As @Omar suggested, I tried adding a `click` event to the `document` scoped to the button and that also didn't work:

```
$("#" + this.queryWindow).on("pageshow", function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#' + self.queryButton, function() {console.log("click");});
});
```

I had a closer look at the samples in the jQuery Mobile docs and those buttons are rendered exactly the same way as mine, but those buttons still honor the click event despite being hidden.

If I programmatically call `$('#querySubmit').click()` it calls `self._performQuery`, but it won't recognize a user click.

---

**Solution**:

So I feel a little dumb on this one after hitting my head against a wall for 2 days.  It turns out that in one of my css stylesheets I created a class called `ui-btn-hidden` with `display: none`.  Upon further investigation, I realized that the examples in the jQuery Mobile docs had the same class, but did not have `display: none`.  So as it turns out, my own css class was causing the problem all along by overwriting the jQuery Mobile `ui-btn-hidden` class.  I changed the name of my css class to `btn-hide` and all is working.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `$(".ui-btn-hidden input[type=submit]").trigger('click')` or `$(".ui-btn-hidden input[type=submit]").click()`?

Comment: @Satpal - I'm not sure how I would use your examples.  I'm trying to set the function that is run when the button is clicked by the user as opposed to programmatically clicking the button.

Comment: it's wrapped in a div. Give the button an id and attach a `click` event `$(document).on('click', '#btn_id', self._performQuery);`

Comment: @Omar - I tried your suggestion, but still had no luck.

Comment: what does `self` refer to?

Comment: `$(document).on("pageshow", "#" + this.queryWindow, function() {` since the page is dynamic.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter - The code that adds the page dynamically is inside an AMD module.  My application uses a 3rd party API based on dojo so I am create dojo modules for specific tasks.  Since dojo and jQuery scope `this` differently, `self` refers to the instance of the encompassing module that is creating the page.

Comment: check the code in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cdB86/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  I found the problem and edited my post with the solution.  It's going to be one of those days I think.